# NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS , when creating a new form and input fields

Tags: javascript

i am new to javascript and i have been trying things out lately . but i am stuck here in one function which return the error :

```
[10:55:47.027] NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMHTMLFormElement.appendChild] @ http://localhost/myproj/test5.html:15
```

Now let me explain what the code does :
1) i have defined a function called "add" it takes one argument which is a arary of strings.
when it is called , the function creates a  new form and new input's with type "text" and value the same as each string in the argument array.

here is the code :

```
function add(index_array) {

//create the form
    var myform = document.createElement("form");
    myform.id="k_form"
    for ( i =0 ; i <index_array.length ; i ++)
    {
        var mytext = document.createElement("input");
        mytext.tpye="text";
        mytext.value="index_array[i]";
        mytext.id="index_array[i]";
        myform.appendChild("mytext");
        console.log("error");
    }
mydiv=document.getElementById("d_div");
mydiv.appendChild("myform");
}
```

now when i execute it , i get the error displayed above , i cant figure out my mistake can anyone please help with that.
thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to append a string to your form not the node variable

```
myform.appendChild("mytext");
```

should be

```
myform.appendChild(mytext);
```

Also

```
mydiv.appendChild("myform");
```

should be

```
mydiv.appendChild(myform);
```

Comment: HI Musa , thanks it works now , however it displays all the input fields side by side as in horizontally. can i use document.getElementById("d_div").innerHTML=
<br/>" in the for loop to introduce line breaks ? d_div is a id of division

Comment: @user1841314 if you want them one to a line you can make them block level elements or wrap each one in a block level elements or put a `<br>` after each one etc.